# append html tags to the selected words out of complete sentence angular 2

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I have a component which receives sentences in a JSON object which each sentence comes with an array of words associated with different colours.

Following is the snippet of component

```
    export class ExampleComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

      ngOnInit() {this._getChats(userId);}

      private _getData(userId: string)  {
        this.dataSub = this.api
         .getDataList$()
         .subscribe(
           res => {
             this.data = res.result.data;
          },
          error => {
           console.log(error);
         });
      }
    }
```

Data I am getting is as follows:

```
[{
   "message": "Attention! The user already exists.",
   "words": [
    {"word": "user", "color": "#ffddcc"},
    {"word": "Attention!", "color": "#ff99cc"},
    {"word": "exists", "color": "#cddcef"}
   ]
 },
 {"message": "Hey! There are no users",
  "words": [{"word": "users","color": "#ffddcc"},{"word": "Hey!","color": "#ff99cc"},{"word": "are","color": "#cddcef"}]},
 {"message": "This is a are recipe","words": [{"word": "are","color": "#ffddcc"},{"word": "recipe","color": "#cddcef"}]}
]
```

And so on.
Now I am currently showing these sentences in my html as follows

```
 <div *ngFor="let dt of data">{{dt.message | formatData:dt.words}}</div>
```

My problem is that I want to replace all the words mentioned in the array with span tag of the respective colour codes like below

```
 <div><span style="color:#ff99cc">Attention!</span> The <span style="color:#ffddcc">user</span> already <span style="color:#cddcef">exists</span>.
```

I tried to create a custom pipe to identify and replace the string. But I am stuck here.

Following is the custom pipe I wrote.

```
   export class FormatDataPipe implements PipeTransform {
     transform(value: string, args: any) {
       if(args.length === 0) {
         return value;
       }
       for(let i =0; i < args.length; i++) {
         if(value.includes(args[i].word)) {
           const subVal = `<span style='color:'"` + args[i].color + `"'>` + args[i].token + `</span>`;
           value.replace(args[i].token, subVal);
         }
       }
    }
  }
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Could you add the custom pipe code you have tried and what is the error you are getting?

Comment: Just added the pipe I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pipe needs to use DomSanitizer so that it can inject html into where your string previously was. Then your pipe can replace all instances of the words in the string with the words wrapped in html span tags.

Your new pipe:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';

...

@Pipe({
  name: 'formatData'
})
export class FormatDataPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {}

  transform(message: string, words: any) {
    let htmlString = words.reduce(
        (memo, word) => memo.replace(
          word.word, 
          `<span style="color:${word.color};">${word.word}</span>`
        ),
        message);

    return this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(htmlString);
 }
}
```

Html implementation of pipe:

```
<div *ngFor="let dt of data" [innerHtml]="dt.message | formatData: dt.words"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks,  This is the exact functionality I was looking for :)

Comment: One quick question, Is it possible to add an event on click of the span that I added?

Comment: @1ns4n3 If you need a click, then I would create a component for this. So in your loop of "let dt of data" I would create component <my-component-with-click> and then have the click handled in the component. Within the component then you might want to move the [innerHtml] bit with the pipe so that it's all nicely packaged together. Does that make sense? Pipes can't really bind clicks and it's not the responsibility of pipes to do so anyways

Comment: Yep. I make perfect sense. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I woild say conver the sentence to a word array run an inner loop to render them.

```
<div *ngFor="let dt of data">
  <span *ngFor="let wd of words(dt.message)" style="color:#ffddcc">{{wd.text}}</span>
</div>
```

In your component there will be a method which will take the sentense and convert and return array/object or words

```
words(snts: string) {
 return snts.split('');
}
```